# JavaScript DEFLATE Implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, deflate

Are there any open source DEFLATE encoder implementations for JavaScript? I need it to generate a binary format on the client-side that requires DEFLATE.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe Pako (https://github.com/nodeca/pako) is now the fastest javascript implementation of deflate and other zlib methods (inflate / gzip / ungzip). There are benchmarks on the github page. It also supports chunking if you need to work with big blobs.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this code.

Comment: it is for node.js ...

Comment: `bower install pako`. See readme. It's for the browser.

Comment: I saw readme... did you see the code? as files in dist are being tried to work on browser, they use zlib in lib folder that is node.js without even trying to change it...

Comment: I'm author of this code and i know how it works. This code is written for browser, and works in many browser projects, independent on your opinion.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did notice that (after answering my post on github). Just didn't know that there was `require` implementation in `javascript`, sorry for mess.

Answer (score 24):

I found a DEFLATE encoder and decoder implementation at http://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate and they both work perfectly.

Comment: Note that js-deflate expects strings with 1 byte per character, but JS uses UCS-2 encoding internally. So you should either apply base64 encoding first, or convert to raw UTF-8 (see http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html for conversion methods)

Comment: An example of js-deflate in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mwolfetech/X2NL6/

Comment: If you set compression level to 3 (down from default 6), it duplicates the last character! Also, it will sometimes produce an invalid output.

Comment: previous jsfiddle doesnt work due to wrong content type. Heres a fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2NL6/263/

Comment: I can't get this library's output to be accepted by any other library. worthless.

Comment: The fiddle example there Yaroslav now gives the length of the 64encoded raw.