# Compression in c# and decompression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, compression

I am generating JavaScript file in C#. There is a numeric array to be written in the JavaScript file. The array can sometimes be very large so can anyone suggest a strong compression method to write compressed data using C# and decompress at run-time from JavaScript. 
Currently I am using LZW compression/decompression but it is not sufficient in my case.

Comment: You could just enable "static/dynamic content compression" in IIS and let the web server and client handle it for you.

Comment: There was http://stackoverflow.com/q/2233062/613130 . You would have to check if it is compatible with `DeflateStream` of .NET

Comment: You should know that compression rate depends on content you can not compress any thing at any rate.