# How Compress TypedArrays/ArrayBuffers for storage and transmission

Tags: compression, storage, typed-arrays, transmission

We started using images for convenient storage of TypedArrays via the ImageData object of canvas. But this fails due to [pre-multiplying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497925/how-can-i-stop-the-alpha-premultiplication-with-canvas-imagedata) .. limiting us to 24 bits of data. We're limping along with this but would love a 32 bit solution.

We want to convert to use of any TypedArray or its ArrayBuffer. But these suffer from lack of compression.

Any interesting ways to compress them? [LZMA-JS](https://github.com/nmrugg/LZMA-JS/blob/master/readme.md)? [JSzip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)? Figure out how to make non-premultiplied pngs? Other?

Comment: What sort of data is in there?

Comment: Typed Arrays of any kind, 256x256 "tiles". A 256 X 256 tile has a raw data size of 64 KBytes per 8-bits of cell/pixel depth. So for 8-, 16-, 32- and 64-bit depths, the sizes are 64K, 128K, 256K, and 512K, respectively. The data can be of any sort useful for our projects: elevation, elapsed time, population ... i.e. all the typed data types.

Comment: What is actually is matters for preprocessing, for example elevation can probably be decorrelated well by subtracting the average of the top and left samples from it. You may also investigate how bzip2-like compression performs on your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageData *will* provide you with 32-bits (RGB + alpha channel). The pre-multipling part refer to the *alpha channel* and the rounding errors due to integer values being used (there is no way around this unless you want to make a custom floating point based bitmap, which is possible but slow(er)). You would still get 32-bit data but with some rounding errors here and there.

For the data you could then use the [Pako implementation](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) of the zlib port for JavaScript. It's fast and 100% compatible with the original implementation result-wise, and offers good compression.

It returns an `Uint8Array` which can be converted to a Blob or `ArrayBuffer`  for storage with f.ex. `IndexedDB` or transferred over the net.

#### Example usage

Compress data:

```
// assuming CORS requirements are fulfilled:
var data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height).data;
var comp = pako.deflate(data);
```

Decompress data:

```
try {
  var data = pako.inflate(comp);
  var idata = new ImageData(width, height); // or via getImageData()
  idata.data.set(data);
  ctx.putImageData(idata, x, y);
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: It's been a while .. here's what I've discovered.  1) Using compression on typed arrays and conversion to base64, and compressed again gets typed arrays close to image storage. LZMA appears slower but more compressive. 2) Using a nifty webgl stunt with textures, w/o color profiling or alpha premultiply, and readpixels .. yields a non-distorted translation of image-as-data. I should post a gist on these.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22429252